# Using R with RODBCext and RODBC to execute a SQL stored procedure

Tags: r, sql-server-2008, rodbc

I am using the RODBCext package and the [RODBC](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/) package to execute a stored procedure in SQL server 2008 using R.  If I use this code the stored procedure works.

```
query <- "EXEC [dbo].[usp_SchoolMerge] @Number = ?, 
                                       @Name = ?, 
                                       @Type = ?, 
                                       @Comments = ?, 
                                       @DualEnrollment =?, 
                                       @CEP = ?, 
                                       @DistrictGuidId = ?,
                                       @ImportName = ?,
                                       @ImportID = ?"

query <- gsub("[[:space:]]+", " ", query)

con2 <- odbcConnect("database", uid="userid", pwd="password")

for(i in 1:nrow(us11_12_00_school)) {

  sqlExecute(con2, query, us11_12_00_school[i,])

}

odbcClose(con2)
```

If I try to use the vectorized form explained [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBCext/vignettes/Parameterized_SQL_queries.html) under 2.3.2 Using parameterized queries.

```
query <- "EXEC [dbo].[usp_SchoolMerge] @Number = ?, 
                                       @Name = ?, 
                                       @Type = ?, 
                                       @Comments = ?, 
                                       @DualEnrollment =?, 
                                       @CEP = ?, 
                                       @DistrictGuidId = ?,
                                       @ImportName = ?,
                                       @ImportID = ?"

query <- gsub("[[:space:]]+", " ", query)

con2 <- odbcConnect("database", uid="userid", pwd="password")

sqlExecute(con2, query, us11_12_00_school)

odbcClose(con2)
```

I get this error in R.

```
Error in sqlExecute(con2, query, us11_12_00_school) : 
  24000 0 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid cursor state
[RODBCext] Error: SQLExecute failed
```

If I use a data frame with only one row the vectorized code works.  Anyone else had this problem?  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have both `RODBC` and `RODBCext` loaded? If so, there may be a namespace conflict that could be resolved by using `RODBCext::sqlExecute` instead of just `sqlExecute`.

Comment: I do have both `RODBC` and `RODBCext` loaded. `RODBC` is required by `RODBCext`. I tried using `RODBCext::sqlExecute(con2, query, us11_12_00_school)` but I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to use only the first column of the `us11_12_00_school` - which you pass in the loop-version of the function with `us11_12_00_school[i,]`. In the vectorised version though, you pass in the whole dataframe!

I havent tested it out, but i guess passing the dataframe as `us11_12_00_school[1,]` in the vectorised version would give you the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

I use the code below, and seems to work well. Hopefully it helps you too.

```
require(RODBC)
require(RODBCext)

ExecuteQuery <- function(query, arguments){

  dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};server=SereverName;database=DbName;trusted_connection=yes')
  if(missing(arguments))
    result <- sqlExecute(dbhandle, query = query, fetch = TRUE)  
  else
    result <- sqlExecute(dbhandle, query =query, data=arguments, TRUE)  
  close(dbhandle)
  return(result)
}

CallProcWithSomeParams <- function(param1, param2){

  ExecuteQuery('exec dbo.procName ?, ?', data.frame(param1, param2))
}
```