# Execute stored procedure and read OUTPUT parameter value together with result set

Tags: r, stored-procedures, rodbc, r-dbi

I want to execute a stored procedure on a (Microsoft) SQL Server (2012) that has an `OUTPUT` parameter and want to read the result set as well as the output value(s) back into R.

Is there a way to

- get the OUTPUT parameter value
- and at the same time (without executing the stored procedure a second time) also
- get the result set of the stored procedure?

Example for my current work-around (using `RODBCext` instead of `RODBC` to prevent SQL code injection):

```
-- example stored procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE output_test  
   @ID     INT,  
   @result INT OUTPUT  
AS  
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON
   SELECT @result = 42                        -- OUTPUT parameter
   -- FROM whateveryouwant
   -- WHERE ID = @ID
   SELECT * FROM anothertable WHERE ID = @ID  -- result set
END
```

Work-around in R using `RODBCext` (would also work with `RODBC` if I'd paste the ID into the `sql` query string):

```
library(RODBCext)

con <- odbcConnect("TEST_DATABASE")

# first query to get the OUTPUT parameter
sql <- "DECLARE @result_output INT;
        EXECUTE output_test @ID = ?, @result = @result_output OUTPUT;
        SELECT @result_output AS result"
result <- RODBCext::sqlExecute(con, query = sql, data = list(ID = 100), fetch = TRUE)

# second query to get the result set
sql2 <- "EXECUTE output_test @ID = ?, @result = @result_output OUTPUT;"
resultset <- RODBCext::sqlExecute(con, query = sql2, data = list(ID = 100), fetch = TRUE)

odbcClose(con)
```

PS: There are related questions here that do not offer a full solution to my question, e. g.:

- [Execute stored procedure with an Output parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1589466/4468078)
- [Getting SQL stored procedure results into data.frame format using RODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8450832/4468078)
- [Using R with RODBCext and RODBC to execute a SQL stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30898712/4468078)
- [Parameterized queries with RODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16178640/4468078)